# Webpack hot reloading with eslint?fix produces infinity blank lines

Tags: javascript, webpack, eslint, livereload

I am using webPack hot reloading and eslint loader, when I edit a file under certain circunsances (which I could not isolate yet) it adds blank lines add infinitum at the start of the file and then complains about the blank lines.

The JS loading part is:

```
{
  const cacheDir = (process.env.CACHE_DIRECTORY ? process.env.CACHE_DIRECTORY : 'true')
  return {

    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.jsx?$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
          loaders: [
            `babel?cacheDirectory=${cacheDir}`, // presets on .babelrc
            'eslint-loader?fix'
          ],
          include: paths
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The HRE loading part is:

```
  import webpack from 'webpack'
  const devServer = (options) => {
    return {
      devServer: {
        hot: true,
        inline: true,
        stats: 'errors-only',
        host: options.host,
        port: options.port,
        historyApiFallback: true
      },
      plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin({
          multiStep: true
        })
      ]
    }
  }
  export default devServer
  export {devServer}
```

And finally the .eslintrc is :

```
module.exports = {
  "extends": ["standard", "standard-jsx"],
  "plugins": [
    "flowtype",
  ],
  rules: {
    "flowtype/define-flow-type": 2,
    "flowtype/use-flow-type": 2
  }
}
```

On which standard is [this plugin](https://github.com/feross/eslint-config-standard) and standard-jx is [this one](https://github.com/feross/eslint-config-standard-jsx).

Is anybody aware of what could cause a blank line insertion at the beginning of the file?

Thanks.